# MUI how to change the color of the TimePicker in the TextField

Tags: typescript, material-ui, components

I have a component TextField which shows a TimePicker, how to stylize this TimePicker, when I try to inspect it doesn't show anything. For example how to change the color? [mine TimePicker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uD4Fn.png) [But i need this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PJG5W.png)

```
> import { TextField } from '@mui/material';
> import { DateTime } from 'luxon';
> import { FC, useCallback, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
> 
> import styles from './styles.module.scss';
> import { DateTimePickerProps } from './types';
> 
> export const TimePicker: FC<DateTimePickerProps> = ({
> name,
> value,
> label,
> inputFormat,
> size,
> onChange,
>   ...props
> }) => {
> const [currentValue, setCurrentValue] = useState<DateTime | null>(null);
> 
> const handleChange = useCallback(
>     (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
> const newValue = DateTime.fromJSDate(event.target.valueAsDate!);
> setCurrentValue(newValue);
> onChange?.(newValue.toJSDate());
>     },
> [onChange]
>   );
> 
> return (
>     <TextField
>       {...props}
> classes={{
> root: styles.timePicker,
>       }}
> id="time"
> label="Alarm clock"
> type="time"
> variant='standard'
> size={size}
> onChange={handleChange}
> defaultValue="07:30"
> InputLabelProps={{
> shrink: true,
>       }}
> inputProps={{
> step: 300, // 5 min
>       }}
> sx={{ width: 150 }}
>     />
>   );
> };
```